# Placement of page numbers is too low

Tags: margins

I'm trying to set page numbering but somehow it ends up lower than it should and the numbers touch the edge of the page, which looks strange and is exactly what I don't want it to look like. How can I adjust the position of the numbers?
I didn't use any settings for page numbering. I use several packages, maybe it has something to do with it

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage[margin={1cm, 1cm}]{geometry}
```

Comment: ok that works thanks. OK next time I'll use that site...

Comment: Please post a minimal working example and, if you've already found a solution, consider self-answering. (I apologize for my brevity, but a phone is not a terribly powerful tool of productivity.)

Answer (score 9):

Assuming that this is only for saving paper, you can pass these options to `geometry`:

```
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm,footskip=.5cm]{geometry}
```

*Never* use `a4wide`, it's outdated, obsolete and buggy. Just `geometry` suffices.

Answer (score 2):

The `geometry` package sets the margins of the 'textblock'; the running headers and footers like outside this. If you want the footer to be 1cm from the bottom of the page, add the `includefoot` option to the `geometry` package. (There is an analogous `includehead` option, and an `includeheadfoot` option that combines the two.)

Answer (score -1):

OK I chose simple solution that worked for me

```
\usepackage[margin = 1cm, bottom = 1.5cm]{geometry}
```