# LaTeX: a4wide package and hungarian settings "input stack size" exceeds

Tags: errors

I have a file that compiled on Ubuntu 12.04 and now (with Ubuntu 14.04, a fresh install, TeXLive 2013, packages from the Ubuntu repository) not. I purged the file, and I find that without a4wide package it works. It is an error in a4wide or I should reset some variables in the texmf.cnf file?

The error message is:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
```

The example.tex is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{a4wide}

\begin{document}

\title{This is the title}
\author{This is my name}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

I have used pdflatex, but the error is same with latex command as well.

I have not used non-ASCII characters as [in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64893/error-latex-tex-capacity-exceeded-sorry-input-stack-size-5000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114004/6341) writes, that a4wide is buggy and outdated, we should use geometry package instead.

I have tried the row was mention there:

```
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm,footskip=.5cm]{geometry}
```

and the result is quite the same as I had on my earlier OS.

Comment: The top entry on CTAN regarding this packages says *This pack­age in­creases the width of the type­set area of an a4 page. This sort of op­er­a­tion is ca­pa­ble of pro­duc­ing ty­po­graph­i­cally poor re­sults; the op­er­a­tion it­self is bet­ter pro­vided by the ge­om­e­try pack­age.* ... which fits to your findings ;-)